# Обновление данных сервера Python при каждом запросе от клиента

Tags: python, json, сервер, flask

Суть вопроса такая: есть простенький REST API с flask и jsonify, формирующий определенные данные и отправляющий их в виде json при запросе от клиента. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было изменить данные и при запросах они были уже обновленными у клиента, без перезапуска сервера? В какую сторону копать, чтобы разобраться с динамическими данными?

Возможно вопрос глупый, но не осуждайте, пока совершенно не разбираюсь в серверной части и Python.

Answer (score 0):

В общем и целом, вам нужно хранилище данных в каком-то виде. В каком именно - зависит от того, сколько этих данных, насколько они структурированы и т. д.

В простейшем случае это может быть просто файл, в который вы вводите информацию. Клиенту будет отдаваться весь этот файл или его часть.

Де-факто стандартом для таких случаев является реляционная база данных. Их много, для самых разных задач. Для начала можно посмотреть в сторону [SQLite,](https://sqlite.org/index.html) простой БД, хранящейся в одном файле.

Comment: А подскажите, в эту БД добавляются данные вручную и при запросе данные берутся оттуда? Рассматривал SQLAlchemy для сервера, это подойдет?

Comment: В БД можно добавлять данные вручную на первом этапе, но скорее всего вам захочется добавить какой-то интерфейс для ввода данных.
SQLAlchemy - хороший выбор, есть даже биндинги для Flask.
Кстати, есть такая вещь, как Flask-Admin для управления данными в БД. Я сам, правда, не пробовал.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Сейчас вот если проще поступить - скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать обращение к файлу, когда поступает запрос? И чтобы jsonify отправлял данные из него?

@app.route('/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify(tasks)